# Understanding git branches in Visual Studio

Tags: git, azure-devops

My familiarity with Git for source control is only via Visual Studio.

We use Azure DevOps for source control, and from there I create a feature branch by right clicking an existing branch and selecting New Branch.

I do my development, test, etc, and merge it into a parent branch. I then delete the branch from DevOps.

Within Visual Studio (the github extension for VS), under Branches, I still see all of the previously deleted branches. Under "remotes/origin" - which to me sounds like remote branches meaning DevOps, the ones I have deleted are still listed. Right clicking on any of them offers a "Delete branch from Remote" - but again, it does not exist remotely.

Is this expected behaviour? I would like to keep my dev/VS environment clean, and seeing lots of old branches goes against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is expected behavior. You should consider 3 stages of branches. Local branches that you have created, origin is the last picture you have of the server, and then the actual server branches. Your origin branches will be updated once you fetch the latest data from the server, however it will not remove branches that are no longer on the server unless you fetch prune.

You can fix this by using the following command line
`git fetch --prune`

or go into your visual studio git settings in visual studio
[image]

Select Global settings

[image]

and put prune to true

Afterwards fetch either by going into the branches menu and right click on a origin branch, or go into sync and fetch inside there.